# How to get live data with React Native

Tags: react-native

So as i title says i`m a bit stuck with this question. 
Can someone tell me which technology is better for real-time data refreshing?

1. React Native Push Notification (as i understand it uses Apple Push Notifications if not then its another technology)
2. GraphQL Live / Subscribtion
3. Web sockets
4. Amazon Push Service
5. Anything else

I know that there is no like **BEST** solution. Just maybe some short difference between each of them in terms of price, security, data transfer speed, battery consuming will be super helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push notifications aren't an ideal solution for your purpose. If you need a real-time connection between your app and your server it's better and easier to use WebSockets.

GraphQL Live subscriptions are the next easier way to implement real-time data refreshing but it might be quite harder to integrate GraphQL on the server side.

Indeed, it depends on what you have on the server side.

Comment: I`m using NestJS with its own GraphQL on fastify adapter :)

Comment: Then it would be pretty easy to implement GraphQL Live subscriptions in your case! React Native has great integration with GraphQL via Apollo.

Comment: How about use firebase also?

Comment: Firebase is the next easiest solution but when you will have quite a big amount of data it might be costly for you.